# image attach option is not coming after taking image from camera

Tags: android

frnds,on clicking on button i open camera for taking picture ,i take picture successfull and now only two option is coming after clicking pic,"save" and "Discard",there is not any option for attaching the camera clicked image so how to attach image and display image in next view?

my code is ...

```
       public void function2(int id){



               Intent cameraIntent = new   Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                              startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

        }


         public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

             if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST||requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                try{
                    try{
                      selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                    //OI FILE Manager
                   String  filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

                    //MEDIA GALLERY
                   selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                    //DEBUG PURPOSE - you can delete this if you want
                    if(selectedImagePath!=null){

                         Intent i=new Intent(MainMenu.this,Imageprview.class);
                          startActivity(i);
                          System.out.println(selectedImagePath);
                    }

                    else
                        System.out.println("selectedImagePath is null");
                    if(filemanagerstring!=null)
                        System.out.println(filemanagerstring);
                    else System.out.println("filemanagerstring is null");

                    //NOW WE HAVE OUR WANTED STRING
                    if(selectedImagePath!=null)
                        System.out.println("selectedImagePath is the right one for you!");
                    else
                        System.out.println("filemanagerstring is the right one for you!");
                }catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }          }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }     }
        }

        //UPDATED!
        public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if(cursor!=null)
            {
                //HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
                //THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
                int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
            else return null;
        }
```

Comment: I don't get ur question correctly. I think you mean ,After taking the image you need to show in next activity imageview. RIGHT?

Comment: @ashish  yeah u are right,but there is no any option available to go next activty..

Comment: asish can u help me for the same..i will be great full thanks of u...

Comment: YA SURE TRY THIS CODE..IS THIS CODE HELPFUL FOR YOU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such option available.you can save file in to sdcard or any external storage
c the code i have done for saving image in external storage.

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
if(v == imgForPhotograph) {

            path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/photo1.jpg";

            File file = new File(path);
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY);
        }
}


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            System.gc();
            if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY) {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        // Call function MakeFolder to create folder structure if
                        // its not created
                        if(imageBitmap != null) {
                            imageBitmap = null;
                            imageBitmap.recycle();
                        }

                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inSampleSize = 3;
                        imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);


                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); // bm

                           byte[] bmpbyte = baos.toByteArray();
                           //
                        Imagebase64= Base64.encodeToString(bmpbyte, Base64.DEFAULT); // set


                        imgForPhotograph.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                        isImageTaken = true;
                        // Name for image
                        IMAGEPATH = getString(R.string.Image)
                                + System.currentTimeMillis();
                        SaveImageFile(imageBitmap,IMAGEPATH);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Picture Not taken",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

}

All The Best....

Comment: can u tell me when onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) would be called after taking image from camera ,means if there is no attachment option for showing image to next view...

Comment: after u click and save the image thn onActivityResult get called,this is the only way for which u r looking

Comment: hi richa in which company u r working currently?would u share linkedin profile with me? thanks

Comment: @Richa  i am getting the image always in landscape mode only :(. Even though i take pic in portrait mode, it is giving me in landscape mode .. How to solve this issue ??

Answer (score 3):

```
Button btnCam=(Button)findViewById(R.id.camBtn); 
            btnCam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) { 
                    // Intent detailActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),com.rodasys.profile.detailProfile.class);
                     //startActivity(detailActivity);

                    saveImage();


                } });    







     }

     public void saveImage()
     {

         try {

             FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("MyFile.jpeg", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
             fos.close();
             File f = new File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + "MyFile.jpeg");

             Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
             intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
             intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION,90);
             startActivityForResult(intent,IMAGE_CAPTURE);
             //startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f)),IMAGE_CAPTURE);

             }
             catch(IOException e) {

             }

    }

     @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == 0) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                    finish();
                    //imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    //imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
                    Intent detActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),com.rodasys.profile.detailProfile.class);
                    startActivity(detActivity);
                    //Log.d("ANDRO_CAMERA","Picture taken!!!");
                    //
                }
            }
        }
```

IN DETAIL PROFILE ACTIVITY

public class detailProfile extends Activity{

```
String fname=new File(getFilesDir(),"MyFile.jpeg").getAbsolutePath();
```

//USING THIS FILE PATH YOU CAN LOAD THE IMAGE IN THIS ACTIVITY
}

YOU HAVE ANOTHER OPTION YOU CAN PASS THE IMAGE TO THROUGH THE INTENT AT THE TIME OF CREATING THE NEW INTENT AND AFTER THAT YOU CAN ACCESS THAT IMAGE THROUGH THE BUNDLE OBJECT IN THE NEW INTENT.

bytes[] imgs = ... // your image
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("img", imgs);
startActivity(intent)

in detailprofile

bytes[] receiver = getIntent().getExtra("imgs");

//using Byte array you can display your image in ur imageview

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys, this code is working. For camera and stored into sd card:

```
public class CampicsaveActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    FrameLayout frm;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        frm=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.preview);
        Button btnCam=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonClick); 
        btnCam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            { 
                //  Intent detailActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),com.rodasys.profile.detailProfile.class);
                // startActivity(detailActivity);

                saveImage(0);
            } });    

        }

        public void saveImage(int IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        {

            try
            {
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("MyFile.jpeg", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                fos.close();
                File f = new File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + "MyFile.jpeg");

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION,90);
                startActivityForResult(intent,IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                //startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f)),IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {;}
        }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if (requestCode == 0)
            {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {
                    finish();
                    //imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    //imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
                    Intent detActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),CampicsaveActivity.class);
                    startActivity(detActivity);
                    //Log.d("ANDRO_CAMERA","Picture taken!!!");
                    //
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```